# BigQuery: Assess overall read volume per table

Tags: google-bigquery, audit-logging

As an organization, we're following the [data mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mesh) approach. We have many teams that provide the data of their products in BigQuery. The data objects are then accessed by many different teams and departments. Each team uses its own set of projects for providing their data or running queries.

**One of the issues we're facing is while producers know exactly who is accessing their data, they usually have no idea how, how often and for which reason the consumers are accessing their data.**

As a consequence, data is often provided in a way that makes the ingestion quick and easy for the producer, but the consumption more expensive for the consumers. Producers do not seem to care too much because they don't have to pay for the consumption by other teams, and they do not know how often their data is read by others.

What would be quite helpful in this context was an overview about **how frequently which table is used by others and the number of bytes / slots** consumed by these queries and ideally even the queries itself. Is there any way of achieving this?

In the [information schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro), you can only see your own projects queries unless you're an organization admin. How about the  [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs)?

Comment: My gut is saying that the INFORMATION_SCHEMAs are the way to go.  Reading the doc here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs-by-organization ... it seems to say we can get cross project (organization) information by possessing the role BigQuery Resource Viewer at the organization level ... this is far less than being an "Organization Admin".  One could also schedule a replicate job on the desired INFORMATION_SCHEMA table into a dataset and then control latent access to historical data using IAM.

Comment: Hi,as per google docs,this way we can calculate number of slot used(average). Number of slot = total\_slot\_ms / TIMESTAMP\_DIFF(end\_time,start\_time, MILLISECOND). Please refer to documentation for further [information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#calculate_average_slot_utilization). Also, audit logs help you answer the question "Who did what, where, and when?" within your Google Cloud resources. Please refer to [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/introduction-audit-workloads) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/audit-logging).

Comment: Hi @Thomas W, Could you confirm if the above comment helped you or not ?

Comment: @SushmaJeerahalli: For sure the audit log point into the right direction. The thing is, I am not interested in the number of slots but rather in how many money other teams spent in querying my teams tables / views. I introduced an optimization and would love to estimate how much money it saves the organization. So I need to find out which accounts (from other projects) access which portions of my data. It's acceptable to assume they use on demand billing model.